# Writing shell script to list the files in all the directories except few

Tags: linux

I want to list the files in each directory the directory contains sub directories as well, in the directories i should ignore few directories it may be parent directory or sub directory. From the below script i able to list the files only in one directory its not looping around other directories. please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Script which I have tried

```
#!/bin/sh
find * -type d | while IFS= read d; do
    dirname=`basename $d`
        if [ ${dirname} != "Decommissioned" ]; then
          cd $dirname
          find * ! -name . -prune -type f | while read fname; do
             fname=`basename $fname`
             echo $fname
          done
        else
           continue
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all regular files but skipping those in directories named *Decommissioned*, you'd do:

```
find . -name Decommissioned -type d -prune -o -type f -print
```

If you want their basename only, with GNU `find`, you can replace the `-print` with `-printf '%f\n'`. Or POSIXly:

```
find . -name Decommissioned -type d -prune -o -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do;
    printf "%s\n" "${file##*/}"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or if you can guarantee that none of the file names contain newline characters:

```
find . -name Decommissioned -type d -prune -o -type f -print |
  awk -F / '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will ignore the "Decommissioned" directory and list out the files in other directories.

```
find . -type d | while read DirName
do
   echo "${DirName}" | grep "Decommissioned" >/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
   then
        find ${DirName} -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
   fi
done
```

Answer based on the comment

```
bash-4.1$ find .
.
./c
./c/c.txt
./c/c2
./c/c2/c2.txt
./c/c1
./c/c1/c1.txt
./a
./a/a.txt
./a/a2
./a/a2/a2.txt
./a/a1
./a/a1/a1.txt
./b
./b/b2
./b/b2/b2.txt
./b/b1
./b/b1/b1.txt
./b/b.txt

bash-4.1$ find . | grep -vE "a/|b2" | grep "\.txt"
./c/c.txt
./c/c2/c2.txt
./c/c1/c1.txt
./b/b1/b1.txt
./b/b.txt
```

Comment: Hey Kamaraj, thank you for your reply but i am getting error in using grep command                                                                                             
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .                                                          i have below os                                                                                 
 SunOS g2902usdsswf01v 5.10 Generic_150400-52 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: try the above one.

Comment: The files are repeating twice let me explain you the process.

Comment: I have three directories with subdirectories the parent directory are a, b, & c. a1&a2 are subdirectories of a, b1&b2 are subdirectories of b, c1&c2 are subdirectories of c.
The files are arranged like this format a.txt(a), a1.txt(a1), a2.txt(a2), b.txt(b), b1.txt(b1), b2.txt(b2), c.txt(c), c1.txt(c1), c2.txt(c2). 
Now I am trying to list the files like i want to ignore the files in the entire directory a with all its a1&a2 sub directories and want to igonre the files only in the b2 directory not directory b or b1.

Comment: Hey Kamaraj, i tried your script like this                                                        find . -type d | while read DirName
do
   echo "${DirName}" | grep "a" >/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
   then
        find ${DirName} -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
   fi
done                                                                                                                                      I found the files are listing twice, do we need to stop it somewhere to list the files only one time

Comment: see the modified post

Comment: grep -vE option is not working in my solaris OS, hence i used print and below is the command which is giving the result   find . -type d \( -name a -o -name b1 -o -name c2 \) -prune -o -type f -print    /*  I need to view the result the like (first column)folder name (second column) file name  like b b.txt \n b2 b2.txt  \n c c.txt \n c1 c1.txt. Do we have any option to view like the above